# iphone facebook status update fails second time

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

Trying to update facebook status from iPhone app, it updates the status first time but the second time fails giving error message

```
(com.facebook.sdk error5.)
 Error: HTTP status code: 400
```

I am using their sample code, here it is

```
    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Check Out location at my App"];


    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_actions"] allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                  FBSessionState status,
                                                  NSError *errr) 
     {
         [ FBSession setActiveSession:session];
         // session might now be open.
         if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {

           [FBRequestConnection startForPostStatusUpdate:message
                                    completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                                        [self showAlert:message result:result error:error];
                                             }];

                         }
     }];
```

when i try to reupdate status it fail giving the error mentioned above
I am developing for iOS 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you uploded same status again then may be facebook block it

**try different status. you cannot update same status again twice.**